# postscript printing with netcat

Tags: printing, postscript, netcat

How can I use the netcat program for bidirectional communication with a networked postscript printer? Postscript programs frequently send information to the STDOUT and that is difficult to capture over the network. I need bidirectional communication with the printer 9100 port. My answer is below. Does anybody know of a better way?

Comment: So.... What exactly is your question ?

Comment: Any better ideas?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand the problem. You've stated what you are doing but you haven't asked a question, or said what you have a problem with. How can anyone offer a 'better idea' without knowing what problems you have with your current approach ?

Comment: This is more of a how-to for bidirectional printing with netcat. There are no other reports when searching the internet except for simple receipt printers not with postscript and not sending output back to the computer. I have gotten bidirectional printing with serial and parallel ports and when using lpr spoolers sending output to the error channel. I have python programs enabling bi-directional communication to capture postscript output except nothing as simple as netcat. Do you have a better way to capture return output from a postscript program 'print' command?

Comment: IMO posting tutorials isn't the point of stack overflow. This is meant to be a site for seeking help on programming problems. At best you should write a question and then post your own answer. Just sticking a 'how to' as a question is (IMO) inappropriate.

Comment: Done. Thanks, KenS. This was my first OP. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

The netcat program can be used for bidirectional communication with a postscript printer.

I have been using some simple programs to send print jobs directly to a network postscript printer and haven't gotten any return info from the printer until now. I like to communicate directly with the printer instead of sending jobs to a spooler.

There is a little information a few places about printing with netcat just very sparse so I am making this report.

My printer is a Xerox 6500n connected to a router by ethernet cable. I can send postscript programs or pdf files directly to the printer in a variety of ways. Sometimes I want to get answers from the printer and so have a test program to use the printer to convert the input using 'pathforall' and send back the answer. The netcat does this nicely:

```
nc -n 192.168.1.111 9100 < pathforall.ps
```

I then get the desired response. This has been checked and is similar to ghostscript output only slightly off for some reason:

```
$ nc -v -w 5 -n 192.168.1.111 9100 < pathforall.ps
192.168.1.111 9100 (hp-pdl-datastr) open
28.6998 12.2999 moveto
28.6998 9.29996 28.3998 8.09995 25.2998 6.59998 curveto
24.3998 6.09998 21.2999 4.79999 19.0999 4.79999 curveto
15.3999 4.79999 12.4999 7.89996 12.4999 12.5999 curveto
12.4999 12.7999 lineto
12.4999 16.1999 13.5999 21.7999 28.6998 26.7999 curveto
closepath

$ gs pathforall.ps
GPL Ghostscript 9.50 (2019-10-15)
Copyright (C) 2019 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software is supplied under the GNU AGPLv3 and comes with NO WARRANTY:
see the file COPYING for details.
Loading Times-Roman font from /usr/share/ghostscript/fonts/Times-Roman.pfa... 4824712 3114962 3833824 2546359 1 done.
28.6184 12.2615 moveto
28.6184 9.27632 28.3224 8.07977 25.2262 6.57484 curveto
24.3257 6.08141 21.2418 4.78618 19.0461 4.78618 curveto
15.3577 4.78618 12.4589 7.8824 12.4589 12.5576 curveto
12.4589 12.7673 lineto
12.4589 16.1472 13.5567 21.7352 28.6184 26.7188 curveto
28.6184 12.2615 lineto
closepath
```

The netcat allows me to communicate with my printer similar to ghostscript except I don't have the executive mode working yet. Also, be sure to include a 'flush' command in the postscript to get the entire answer sent back.
This can be used for many purposes to get information from the printer.

EDIT: Here is a simple test to see if the printer STDOUT is getting back to the computer:

```
%!
(Hello World\n) print flush
```

EDIT3: Postscript executive mode works using telnet for the Xerox 6500n as suggested by luser droog. See comments below.

Comment: Very cool. If you can connect with input from stdin, try typing `executive` and hit enter a few times. It might give you a prompt. (Used to use telnet for similar interaction with an HP laser printer.)

Comment: Thanks for the info. I tried using netcat to interact with the printer stdin again with no affect. I also installed the telnet and experimented without any response on port 9100. The above edit2 shows where I got the printer to send the prompt except then would not respond to stdin. Many years ago I would use netatalk for the appletalk protocol with good results except that was a large program with complicated setup and not now available in my Void linux distribution. I much prefer the netcat so far.

Comment: Maybe something like `cat executive.ps - | nc IP 9100`. Or just running `nc` with no redirection. It should accept typing. The command you used redirects stdin so it doesn't have it connected to the keyboard anymore. But some other way of running the program should allow it work I think.

Comment: I tried that also with no effect. I now suspect there is a setting in the Xerox preventing the executive communication. I found an old attempt with my Optralaser that worked with the telnet you suggested previously that does not work with the Xerox so I suspect my settings. I am not really too interested in the executive mode because that was not very useful previously. Here is an old result being successful: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SzbJ6yZEvz_S3KXVDhun7bJoegSoCCxQ/view The ShowAllDevParams and ShowParams were installed with exitserver before that test.

Comment: I still think it ought to work, but there are some extra confusing details I left out. The connection usually starts out with the printer side doing *no echo*, so it won't show the letters as you type. Also the printer needs to see at least 2 carriage returns, so if the keyboard side is using line-buffering (probably) then you need to hit enter 3 times for the printer to see the first 2. ... But since you don't actually need this, don't keep trying just for my sake. Just FYI HTH.

Comment: I was able to get the executive mode to work using the PRET tool using python to connect to port 9100. So the problem might be my xterm or CR/LF setup or even netcat and telnet. Maybe putty or some other terminal might work. Here is the log: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1A1a_Gd2SYYzY1f1Tjp9DVIlvRFEvw2WB/view

Comment: Thanks luser droog. The telnet works to gain the executive mode as you suggested. I had failed to start with the postscript shebang. My bad. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KXYkFIbj2_YjhW7Z4anoOPwdzbh6mfMe/view

Answer (score 1):

Here is a bash /dev/tcp alternative for printing without netcat.
This sends to a network PostScript printer using bash if built with --enable-net-redirections. This works with my Void bash and with my Xerox Phaser 6500n and switches between PJL and PostScript. Testing results with other printers would be helpful.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
#   ++++   driverless postscript printing   ++++
#   bash needs --enable-net-redirections build option
#
# for postscript programs with postscript printer only
#
# bash escape is \033 or \e or \E or \x1B

exec 5<>/dev/tcp/192.168.1.111/9100 || exit 1     # change ip as needed

{
 echo -e "\E%-12345X@PJL"           # PJL entrance
 echo @PJL ECHO "$(date)"
 echo @PJL ECHO "setting up printer ..."
 echo @PJL COMMENT Change Printer Settings
 echo @PJL SET COPIES = 1           # modify environment settings
 echo @PJL SET MANUALFEED = off
 echo @PJL ECHO "Starting PostScript Program ..."
 echo @PJL ENTER LANGUAGE = POSTSCRIPT
 echo  "%!"                         # optional
cat "$1" || echo -E "(Hello World\n) print flush"   # if input.ps missing
 echo -e "\004"                     # ctrl-D for end of file
 echo -e "\e%-12345X@PJL"           # back to PJL
 echo @PJL ECHO "Finished PostScript Program."
 echo @PJL RESET                    # unset modified environment settings
 echo @PJL ECHO BYE.
 echo -e "\033%-12345X"             # PJL universal exit
} >&5                               # send to printer

while read -t 122 -r LINE            # timeout after 122 seconds of silence
do
  echo "$LINE"
if [[ "$LINE" =~ @PJL\ ECHO\ BYE. ]]; then break; fi
done <&5

echo "Finished reading printer"

exec 5>&-                           # close
exec 5<&-                           # close both
exit 0
```

Here is the result in my terminal. Be sure to send a file like "print.sh input.ps" or this will happen:

```
$ ./print.sh
cat: '': No such file or directory
@PJL ECHO Mon 20 Apr 2020 07:10:03 AM PDT

@PJL ECHO setting up printer ...

@PJL ECHO Starting PostScript Program ...

Hello World
@PJL ECHO Finished PostScript Program.

@PJL ECHO BYE.
Finished reading printer
```

UPDATE: I have added this here: [github](https://github.com/beginner3456789/postscript-printing-with-bash-dev-tcp)